# Strange PHP string compare effect, could this be made nicer?

Tags: php, string, compare

I've updated a website and found an annoying problem in my pages
I resolved it, but i'm not realy convinced it should look like this.
To me i'm not an PHP expert its strange behaviour could someone explain me whats going on.

I had this code:

```
if($Menu == "index"){
   {if ($Language == "UK"){echo "<td><h1>Welcome</h1>";}
   {if ($Language == "NL"){echo "<td><h1>Welkom </h1>";}
   }
  else
   // if $menu was not index it displayed a hyperlink to Welcome page
```

The string thing here that while the checking for language worked fine.
The comparison for $Menu did not work, even if it contained the word  index
As the whole page was generated on the fly and some string operations where done before
I assumed that maybe, despite i also tested it with

```
   echo "dump Menu variable " . $Menu
```

Which resulted in jut displaying the word index on the page. So maybe there would go something wrong in string types or something like that

So i experimented with

```
  if($Menu === "index")
```

No luck

Well i finally solved it like this

```
  if (strpos($Menu,'index' !==false)
```

Is that really the way it should be done???, I don't feel really comfortable with it.
As to me its strange that for $Language it just works as it should (in my opinion).
Is there is some type problem here, or maybe unwanted endings \n  could i perhaps ehm normalize the string to do a content of readable string comparions or, a different type of equal operator. As it feels to me as $Menu could be handled more easily. Maybe a reformat or but i'm not sure here.

Comment: Yes and thats the strange part of it, because $language works. But $Menu didnt unless i used the strpos trick, and i wonder if i could rewrite the code, to ahum "normalize" the $Menu or so.

Comment: maybe you have a white space in your $Menu variable, try with this comparaison : if($Menu == trim("index")){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks indeed like your index-String is containing whitespaces, instead of strpos you could use `trim( $Menu )` to get rid of them.

But the best would be to prevent their occurence. You could try `echo "dump Menu variable |" . $Menu ."|";` or just `var_dump( $Menu )` to identify the additional characters.

Maybe you could post, your code-segment where $Menu is filled.

(sorry can't just comment)

Comment: Thanks, indeed there was a space in $Menu, as a result of string manipulations earlier in the code. using var_dump solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$Menu = trim($Menu);
$Language = trim($Language);

$langAllowed = ["UK", "NL"]; // zero element is default;
if(!in_array($Language, $langAllowed )) $Language = $langAllowed[0];

$menuLocales=[
    "index" => [
        "UK"=>"Welcome",
        "NL"=>"Welkom "
    ],
    "default"=>[
        "UK"=>"Welcome default (no index)",
        "NL"=>"Welkom default (no index)"
    ]
];

$MenuIndex = isset($menuLocales[ $Menu ]) ? $Menu : "default";
echo "<td><h1>".$menuLocales[ $MenuIndex ][ $Language  ]."</h1>";
```